# Can I Google Maps API Polygon Shapes in an SQL Databse

Tags: javascript, sql, google-maps

For a project, I'm creating a bunch of Google Maps polygons using the JS API. I hand create each polygon using lat and lon coordinates. Can I save these shapes in a SQL database. My goal is for the user to be able to click a button and the polygon loads.

Comment: Sure. They have a json representation or something, right? You can put into a varchar(max) field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using spatial SQL to store data in SQL database.
This will help in using inbuilt spatial operators while querying data.
See below links for reference

[SQL Server Spatial sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server)

[Oracle Spatial sql](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_intro.htm)